# Git, how to list my recently changed files

Tags: git, list, file, diff

how to have `git` to list my recently changed files?

The challenges here are:

- list only file names, which are changed in my recent commits (say 10).
- and due to the huge git I'm working on, my 10th recent commit might be beyond the 100th commits, if using `git` (`log`/`diff`) to show everyone, not just me.

If that's too difficult, I can accept any other solutions that are similar. E.g., would my recently changed files after a certain day be any easier?

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~10 # last 10 commits
```

Now, if it's about *your* commits, it might be a little trickier:

```
git diff --name-status $( git log --author="my name" --pretty=%h | head -n 10 | tail -n 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks, `head -n 10 | tail -n 1` that's _only_ for the latest 10th commit, not _all_ my last 10 commits, right?

Comment: Nope.... cause you are filtering out revisions **not committed** by you when saying `--author` on log... so it's **your** 10th commit going backwards.

Comment: Ah, yep! FTR, I found I need `--author="my name"` in `git diff` command as well. Hmm... even with  `--author="my name"` in `git diff` command, I saw files not changed by me. why?

Answer (score 2):

```
git log -10 --author=me --pretty='' --name-only | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the files modified by commit eacf32 :

```
git show --name-status eacf32
```

If you want to view the files modified by 10 of your commits :

- spot those 10 commits (as suggested by other answers : `git log --author="..."`
- run the above command on the 10 individual commits and aggregate the results